# How to calculate residual standard error for a regression model with log link in R

Tags: r, residuals, standard-error

I want to compare residual standard error across a series of different model specifications as one way of assessing model fit. I assumed that calling `sigma` on a model in R produced the same as manually calculating the formula:

[image: RSE formula]

On a linear model that seems to be the case:

```
data(mtcars)
myModel <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
sigma(myModel)
sqrt(sum(myModel$residuals^2)/myModel$df.residual) # matches sigma
```

But using a log link, they no longer match

```
myLogLinkModel <- glm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
sigma(myLogLinkModel)
sqrt(sum(myLogLinkModel$residuals^2)/myLogLinkModel$df.residual)
```

I thought this must be to do with whether the residuals were being measured on the scale of the link function or the final response variable, but now I'm not so sure.

I can calculate sigma manually, by getting the residuals in terms of the predicted response:

```
mtcars$predicted_mpg <- predict(myLogLinkModel, type = "response")
mtcars$residuals <- mtcars$mpg - mtcars$predicted_mpg
sqrt(sum(mtcars$residuals^2)/myLogLinkModel$df.residual) # matches sigma
```

But if I do the same with residuals on the scale of the link function, I get close but not equal to `sqrt(sum(myLogLinkModel$residuals^2)/myLogLinkModel$df.residual)`:

```
mtcars$predicted_mpg <- predict(myLogLinkModel, type = "link")
mtcars$residuals <- log(mtcars$mpg) - mtcars$predicted_mpg
sqrt(sum(mtcars$residuals^2)/myLogLinkModel$df.residual) # doesn't match manual RSE
```

Is that just a result of rounding errors (?!) or is there something else going on that I've not understood?